# Create/access Javascript global variable created on AJAX call

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

How do I create a Javascript global variable from an AJAX call?  I'm currently getting a undefined error.
I've cut the code to just relevant sections.  I'll add more if requested.

```
#index.php
#(Calls form.php)
  if(ajaxRequest.status == 200){
    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "<script">; #new
    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML += ajaxRequest.responseText;
    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML += "</script">; #new
  }



#form.php
  print("<script>var message = 'Hello World';</script>");
  print("<input type=\"button\" onClick=\"printMessage()\" />");

#index.js
#(Sent to the browser before AJAX. Executed after AJAX call.)
  function printMessage(){
    alert(message);
  }
```

Comment: I'd suspect that the code defining 'var message' is being executed after the index.js is loaded and as a result can't see the variable. If as a test you put 'var message = 'Test'; in your index.js does it work as expected?

Comment: Yes, thats how it currently works.  Since it seems like a scope issue, is there a way to add the var to document?

Comment: You're probably doing this wrong. Why not just use [JSONP][1]?


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: It's a bit of a bodge, but you 'could' put a hidden HTML element on the page <input type="hidden" id="msg"/> and set it's value in form.php and retrieve it again during printMessage using getElementById()

Comment: If I put the function in its own file, then print a JS file include inside innerHTML, would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `<script>` tags added via `innerHTML` don't get executed.

Have a look at: [Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1197575/511300)

If you can use JQuery, this would work:

```
$('#response').html(ajaxRequest.responseText);
```

---

You could also create the `<script>` tag using JavaScript like this:

```
var ajax_response='var message="Hello World!";';

var sc=document.createElement('script');
sc.text=ajax_response;

document.body.appendChild(sc);

alert(message);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6ChZG/

---

Something like this should work:

```
#index.php
#(Calls form.php)
  if(ajaxRequest.status == 200){
    var res=document.getElementById("response");
    res.innerHTML = "<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"printMessage()\" value=\"test\" />";
    var sc=document.createElement('script');
    sc.text=ajaxRequest.responseText;
    res.appendChild(sc);    
  }



#form.php
  print("var message = 'Hello World';");


#index.js
#(Sent to the browser before AJAX. Executed after AJAX call.)
  function printMessage(){
    alert(message);
  }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XbM7v/

Comment: Would creating the <script> tags in Javascript, then creating the variables during the AJAX call work?  Something like the above:
(Just follow the general logic, not the actual js function calls)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Replace `var message` with `message`. Variables not declared as `var ..` are added to global scope.

And, call `printMessage()` **after** the ajax call completes.

```
  if( (ajaxRequest.status == 200 ) && ( ajaxRequest.readyState==4 ) ){
    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    //printMessage() call here...
  }
```

Hope this helps.